# Как правильно создать в БД таблицу, которая будет отвечать за новости?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Допустим, на данный момент я хочу вывести картинку, заголовок, вступительный текст и полный текст (при открытии страницы с новостями). Само собой, в самом начале id, но он не выводится.

Собственно, сама таблица, еще не созданная:

[image]

И у меня вопрос, картинка какой тип должна иметь? Исходя из опыта работы в MS Access, есть специальный тип для медиафайлов, а здесь я его не нашел.

**Альтернативный способ:** хранить картинки отдельно в папке и вызывать их через id (т.е. название картинки будет соответствовать id в БД, тем самым выведется нужная картинка).

Answer (score 1):

**Альтернативный альтернативный способ**: хранить информацию о файлах в отдельной таблице `files`, а в `news` ссылаться на неё. Таким образом вы:

- всегда будете знать, какие файлы у вас используются;
- сможете настроить внешние ключи;
- избавитесь от неочевидной привязки имени файла в файловой системе к строке в БД;
- сможете прикреплять к новости несколько файлов;
- сможете прикреплять файлы не только к новостям.
- сможете воспользоваться стандартной схемой, когда из файла вычисляется хеш и исходя из этого хеша формируется дерево директорий (например, файл с хешем `somehash` хранится в `/files/som/eha/somehash`, это позволяет избежать большого колиечства файлов в одной директории).

Answer (score 1):

Картинки хранятся в различных полях `BLOB` (`TINYBLOB`, `BLOB`, `MEDIUMBLOB`, `LONGBLOB`) отличаются они максимальным размером данных, которые может содержать поле (255, 65 535, 16 777 215, 4 294 967 295 байт)

Answer (score -1):

Кто вообще хранит файлы в бд? Это самое, что ни на есть " Плохая практика". Поля все те, для числовых ставишь тип "int", для заголовка, изображения, вступительного текста - "varchar", ну и само собой для полной новости - тип "text". При создании новости просто заливаешь файл изображения в скажем папку upload/news/*id* на сервере и в бд записываешь лишь ссылку на нее. Все.

Comment: Сохраняя файлы в конкретной файловой системе вы приобретаете проблемы при попытке горизонтального масштабирования. Во всём есть свои плюсы и минусы.

Comment: Эм, а в чем проблема переместить файлы из одного каталога в другой? Затем сменить автозаменой пути в бд? Либо скажем пойти еще проще в в конфиге подключаемом к системе создать константу с путем к каталогу с этими изображениями, а в бд писать, что-то типо <?= Dir_Images_News;? > ну и уже на выводе обрабатывать константу? Вроде, как решена Ваша проблема?

Comment: При чём тут путь к каталогу, если у нас разные сервера в разных датацентрах?

Comment: Что-то я не вижу тут проблемы никакой. Что мешает ссылаться из базы одного сервера в одном дата-центре на файл на другом ВАШЕМ сервере в другом дата-центре. То-ли Вы объяснить не можете толком, то-ли Вас убедил, кто-то в правильности Вашего единоверного решения. ;-)

Comment: `в правильности Вашего единоверного решения` - Я как раз говорю, что в хранении файлов в базе нет ничего плохого, но и против хранения в локальной файловой системе тоже ничего не говорю. Цитирую: `Во всём есть свои плюсы и минусы`. То что вы не видите проблемы, не значит, что её нет.

Comment: Тогда прошу меня извинить, не правильно Вас понял, хотя и откровенно не согласен и придерживаюсь более удобного, не загружающего бд решения, - то что предложил. А плюсов я действительно никаких не вижу в подходе автора вопроса, одни минусы.